# How to access variable and its value from Azure static web app - Keyvault in Gatsbyjs project

Tags: gatsby, pipeline, azure-keyvault

I have created an app in GatsbyJs + ReactJS. I was asked to get the clientID and loginScope from Azure static web app where variables created with hidden value by integrating with Azure KeyVault. I do not know how to access those variables. I need clientid and loginscope to let the user to get authorised. I tried the following.

1. .env.production

   GATSBY_ClientID = process.env.ClientID

   GATSBY_loginScope = process.env.loginScope
2. Used DefaultAzureCredentials

   const credential = new DefaultAzureCredential();

   const keyVaultName = process.env["<my_keyvault_name>"];

   if(!keyVaultName) throw new Error("KEY_VAULT_NAME is empty");

   const url = "https://" + keyVaultName + ".vault.azure.net";

   const client = new SecretClient(url, credential);

   // Read the secret we created

   const secret = await client.getSecret("ClientID");

   alert(secret);

   console.log("secret: ", secret);

It gave me an error saying

```
DefaultAzureCredential is not supported in the browser. Use InteractiveBrowserCredential 
instead.
```

I committed the code in Github and ran Azure Pipeline. It should automatically pick up those two from Azure Key Vault and authorize the user